# Process Appears and Disappears Randomly in `top`

Tags: linux, debian, top

Very similar in theme to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/406489/load-causing-processes-disappearing-from-top-ps-o-pcpu-shows-bogus-numbers), but that refers specifically to high-load processes; in my case, it's a quite unobtrusive task.  It's not a matter of falling off the bottom of the terminal space; I can filter by that PID and see the one line appear and disappear over time.  The task isn't exiting, as the PID is the same and the CPU time (when visible!) continues to trickle upward.  Could this be another case of a procps bug, as mentioned in the other question?

It happens to be a Python3 process, if that's relevant.